# What is causing the function to run twice in a react component where there seems to be no prop/state/context change?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

Problem: I want to create an admin page where a user can create new posts, this site shall also show the already published posts of that user. To get the already published posts I am running a firestore query - when I log the data of the query I get the correct posts, however they are logged twice. Now I need help finding out what causes my function to execute twice?

Admin Page

```
const getUserPostsWithID = async (userID) =>{
  const q = query(collection(db,`users/${userID}/posts`));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
  });
}
//TODO fix double execution of getUserPostsWithID

export default function AdminPage() {
  const {userID} = useContext(authContext);
  const posts = getUserPostsWithID(userID);
  


  return (
    <Authcheck>
      <h1>The Admin Page</h1>
      <PostList></PostList>
    </Authcheck>
  );
}
function PostList() {

  return <PostFeed></PostFeed>;
}
```

Context Component

```
export const authContext = createContext({
  user: "null",
  username: "null",
  userID: "null",
});

export default function AuthenticationContext(props) {
  const [googleUser, setGoogleUser] = useState(null);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState(null);
  const [userID, setUserID] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUsername = async (uid) => {
      const docRef = doc(db, `users/${uid}`);
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
      console.log("Database Read Executed");
      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        setUsername(docSnap.data().username);
      } else {
        setUsername(null);
      }
    };

    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setGoogleUser(user.displayName);
        setUserID(user.uid);
        getUsername(user.uid);
      } else {
        setGoogleUser(null);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  

  return (
    <authContext.Provider value={{ user: googleUser, username: username , userID: userID}}>
      {props.children}
    </authContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Edit: Screenshot of Console
[image]

Thank you for your help, it is very appreciated! :)

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot your given code? Have you already checked if there's no function calling/using the `AdminPage()`?

Comment: Hey Marc, thank you for your comment - I think I have gotten to the crux with a slightly different useEffect statement. Even though it works now I am not quite sure about the why.

Comment: turn off `React.strict` components from main.js

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getUserPostsWithID = async (userID) => {
      const q = query(collection(db, `users/${userID}/posts`));
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
      console.log("Database Read Executed");
      const postArr = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        postArr.push(postToJSON(doc));
      });
      setPostState(postArr);
    };
    getUserPostsWithID(userID);
  }, []);
```

This code now prevents double execution even though I am not quite sure why.